# .gitignore file doesn't seem to ignore anything at all

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore, lockfile

I am working on a Unity project with Gitlab as my version control system. As I just started on this project I made the repository a few hours ago. I initialized a README file and then cloned it into my PC.

Once cloned into it, I added a Unity gitignore file and called it ".gitignore"
Then I pushed the .gitignore file to the origin master again.
Once that was done, I added the fresh Unity project into the git. Then, when I did "git add ." ALL the files were added, also all ignored files and instantly everything broke down due to the fact that the unityLockFile was blocking the whole progress from continuing. I have tried to change a few variables in the .gitignore after the problem but git just doesn't seem to ignore anything.

In the file hierarchy in Windows the green checkmark is visible on the .gitignore file.

I have tried to change some variables in the .gitignore. I also tried to push normally when unity was closed, but it was still pushing way too many things. If I would try to pull it into my friends PC, it would give tons and tons of merge conflicts due to the fact that every single file was being send to him.

This is the inside of the .gitignore file V

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory

/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/

# Never ignore Asset meta data
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# TextMesh Pro files
[Aa]ssets/TextMesh*Pro/

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties
```

I would like to know how to fix the problem of git not ignoring any files to prevent any further problems with the ongoing problem.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the top level of you git repo?, its important to know exactly where your gitignore is in relation to your files, for example if you have `README` `.gitignore` `unityProjectFolder` then your git ignore wouldn't work as it is for that level.

Comment: it may also have something to do with the `/[Ll]ibrary/` in my project i have the README and .gitignore in the same directory as my unity project files and I just use `[Ll]ibrary/`  I am assuming the first / is possibly causing an issue, and you could possible try `./[Ll]ibrary/`

Comment: Heres how to git repo looks like: http://prntscr.com/nhofdb

Comment: @VoidCallerZ can you try changing `/[Ll]ibrary/` to `*/[Ll]ibrary/` before adding your unity project?

Comment: @VoidCallerZ basically follow the same format for everything that isnt in the same folder as the gitignore

Comment: I do have 1 more little question, and that is how I can ignore "/Library/ShaderCache.db" as this is failing to unlink

Comment: you might have to git rm it and physically delete it...

Answer (score 0):

As Eddge suggested in the comments, the solution was to remove the leading path separator (`/`) in front of the folders to be ignored.